# Files differ after being rsync'ed

Tags: linux, debian, rsync, backup, ext4

**TLDR;**

**After running `rsync -aPc --no-inc-recursive --stats <source> <destination>` the files differ.**

I'm bucking up my homelab NAS and I wanted to verify that the files are exactly the same.

My system specs:

- openmediavault 5.6.13-1 (Debian) run in a Proxmox VM
- source filesystem: EXT4
- destination filesystem: EXT4
- the drives are passed through to the motherboard, connected with SATA cables

I have created a script that runs in the background. It rscyncs the files first and then compares them to validate the backup:

```
echo "rsync /documents"
rsync -aPc --no-inc-recursive --stats /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID1/documents /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID2
echo "rsync /photos"
rsync -aPc --no-inc-recursive --stats /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID1/photos /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID2
echo "rsync /movies"
rsync -aPc --no-inc-recursive --stats /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID1/movies /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID2
echo "rsync /music"
rsync -aPc --no-inc-recursive --stats /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID1/music /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID2
echo "rsync /downloads"
rsync -aPc --no-inc-recursive --stats /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID1/downloads /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID2

echo "cmp all start"
find /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID1 -type f -exec sh -c '
    for f; do
        cmp "$f" /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID2"${f#/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID1}"
    done
' sh {} +
echo "cmp all finish"
```

The cmp command gives me some "errors" like: `/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID1/photos/DSC01010.ARW /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID2/photos/DSC01010.ARW differ: byte 70406147, line 285859`.

What causes the issues?

How can I make sure the files are copied correctly?

Comment: How do you know for a fact that the files are being copied incorrectly?  There appears to be ample opportunity for the files on ID1 to be modified after they are `rsync`ed to ID2, but before they are checked by your script.  Please edit your post and add the output of: `ls -l /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID1/photos/DSC01010.ARW /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID2/photos/DSC01010.ARW` and `sha256sum /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID1/photos/DSC01010.ARW /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-ID2/photos/DSC01010.ARW`.

Answer (score 0):

All of the `rsync` errors I've ever seen have been caused by faulty RAM or a corrupt filesystem (one time, a loose SCSI cable). You can check RAM with Memtest86+ and run `e2fsck` on your filesystem to find/fix problems.

Make sure all hardware connectors are seated and working properly (loose SCSI/IDE/SATA/USB cable)

If you are using a USB stick to `rsync` over, these wear out over time and don't usually get fsck'd at system boot so errors aren't as easily detected. A simple `e2fsck/fsck` will help here too.

Comment: I've checked the ram with Memtest86+ before. Also, I replaced my SATA cables. I haven't run e2fsck tho (only the SMART test). I'll try it now.

BTW do you know how to retry the error using only one disk? That way it would be easier to diagnose the issue for me.

Comment: e2fsck gives no errors. I'll try to run my script with only one RAM stick...

Comment: > how to retry the error using only one disk? Not sure what you mean. So `e2fsck` won't check hardware errors on the drive, so you may want to try `smartctl` and run a disk test individually, something like `smartctl --attributes --log=selftest --quietmode=errorsonly /dev/sda`